# DJANGO background task always on

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I am currently developing an Django based web application which does some sentiment processing on global tweets and displays them on  a google map. I am currently stuck in one part that how do i get the Django application to keep collecting tweets in the background? like even if somebody is not accessing the web link of application, It should keep on collecting tweets and store them in Amazon elastic search. I have searched Google and reference materials but there are different views which are confusing. Can anybody help me? The application will be deployed on amazon elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Check out using [Celery + Redis](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/) for asynchronous tasks.

Comment: You need a worker instance for async tasks. You can use Celery, Redis for Broker (or RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS) and then the tasks you created will be run on your worker instance.